# An equation in tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the numbers of solutions of below equation:
$$| \mathbb Z_n \otimes \mathbb Z_{12}| =\frac{n}{2} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to prove that $\Bbb Z_n\otimes\Bbb Z_m\cong\Bbb Z_{\gcd(n,m)}$.

Comment: @rese, n=8 , 24